# docker run error: Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

When I try to input the command:
`docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`
it return the info:

```
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/getting-started
docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Then I try to run this command
`docker run hello-world`

the return is below:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Docker Desktop is runnning
[image]

dockerd is OK:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources>dockerd
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.396277500+08:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.418789600+08:00" level=info msg="Windows default isolation mode: hyperv"
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.425351400+08:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.425882900+08:00" level=info msg="Restoring existing overlay networks from HNS into docker"
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.519394800+08:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.520494300+08:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=459d0df graphdriver(s)=windowsfilter version=20.10.12
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.520494300+08:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
time="2022-03-23T10:59:57.529095300+08:00" level=info msg="API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine"
time="2022-03-23T11:07:34.608125700+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries"
time="2022-03-23T11:09:28.499155000+08:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries"
time="2022-03-23T11:19:23.557693900+08:00" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"
time="2022-03-23T11:19:23.558115100+08:00" level=info msg="Ignoring extra error returned from registry: unauthorized: authentication required"
```

I dont know how to do next. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/) for WSL2 you must run a linux terminal to use Docker command.